# Click on dynamically added table row to get index number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

APIs used

- Parse.js: 1.4.2
- JQuery: 1.11.2 and 1.10.3 (U.I.)
- Twitter Bootstrap: 3.3.4

I am designing a business website and I got stuck on this small section. What I am trying to write is a bootstrap table which is populated by Parse.com to present some information. A user should be able to click on the rows and edit/delete them at will. I don't need to figure out the edit/removal process; what I need is the first step of detecting an onclick on a given row. I have tried a variety of options in JQuery such as

```
$("table tr").click(function(){
    alert (this.rowIndex);
});
```

and

```
$('.dashboard_nav_team_settings_content').find('tr').click( function(){
  alert('You clicked row '+ ($(this).index()+1) );
});
```

However, neither work. By "not work", I mean the onclick listener is never fired to begin with. I tried referencing be "any table" to the class name I gave "bowlsettingtable". Below is an image of the populated table.

[image: Coolest table ever]

Part of the problem might reside in the fact that I am populating each row dynamically via Parse.com but I thought it shouldn't have an issue at all if I give the generic row a class name and reference it in my onclick listener.

Below is a stripped down HTML snippet regarding the code I am working with. I am populating everything into the "dashboard_nav_team_settings_content" div tag.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title></title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/custom/dashboardMain.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" /> 

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- timepicker -->
    <!-- http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/ -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom/jquery.timepicker.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom/site.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- navigation bar at the top -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="" id="dashboard_home_title_link">Ethics Bowls</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#" id="dashboard_help">Help</a></li>
            <li><a href="" id="dashboard_log_out">Log Out</a></li>
          </ul>
          <!--<form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
          </form> -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">


        <!-- Team Settings CONTENT -->
        <div id="dashboard_nav_team_settings_content">

        </div><!--/ Team Settings CONTENT -->


       </div><!--/.col-xs-12.col-sm-9-->        

        <!-- left side navigation bar for content area -->
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar">
          <div class="list-group">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" id="dashboard_nav_home">Home</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" id="dashboard_nav_ethic_bowls">Create and Manage Bowls</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" id="dashboard_nav_team_settings"> Bowl Settings</a>
          </div>
        </div><!--/.sidebar-offcanvas-->
      </div><!--/row-->

      <hr>

      <footer>
        <p>&copy; </p>
      </footer>

    </div><!--/.container-->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/parse/dashboardMainjs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/parse/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/parse/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/parse/site.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Below is a stripped down version of the Jquery/Javascript file I am writing. The section I am dealing with is the "$("#dashboard_nav_team_settings").click(function(event)" which loads when I get on this specific page.

```
// global to help with editing ethic bowl objects
var row_data = [];
var rowNumber = 0;
var parseQueryList = [];
var userQueryList = [];
var editRowNumber = 0;
var currentObjectId = '';
var currentUser;
var createTitle;
var createLocation;
var createStartDate;
var createEndDate;
var studentImage = "images/dashboard_page/student.jpg";
var coachImage = "images/dashboard_page/coach.jpg";
var organizerImage = "images/dashboard_page/organizer.jpg";

// some of these ^ may be useless but I didn't want to spend forever deleting them to this snippet

$(function() 
{   
    Parse.$ = jQuery;
    Parse.initialize("KEY", "KEY");

    setUp();

    // <TRIED ALL OF THESE AND NONE WORKED>
    $(".bowlsettingtable").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).closest('td').parent()[0].sectionRowIndex);
    });

    $("table tr").click(function(){
        alert(this.rowIndex);
    });

    $('#dashboard_ethic_bowl_list').find('tr').click( function(){
        alert('You clicked row '+ ($(this).index()+1) );
    });
    // </TRIED ALL OF THESE AND NONE WORKED>

    $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
        $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active')
    });

    $("#dashboard_nav_team_settings").click(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();

        //<TEAM SETTINGS PAGE>
        for(var i = 0; i < parseQueryList.length; i++)
        {
            // how to truncate a string
            var title = '';
            title = parseQueryList[i].get('title');

            var team_settings_content = "";
            team_settings_content = 
                '<div class="panel panel-primary">' +
                    '<div class="panel-heading">' +
                        '<h3 class="panel-title" style="display:inline-block;">' + title + '</h3>'+
                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" style="position:relative; display:block; float:right; bottom:5px">Email All</button>' +
                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" style="position:relative; display:block; float:right; right: 10px; bottom:5px">Add</button>' +
                        '<p style="position:relative; display:block; float:right; right:20px"><i>Hint:</i> Click on any row to edit/delete it.</p>'+
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="panel-body">' +
                        '<div class="col-md-12 table-responsive">' +
                            '<table class="table table-striped table-hover bowlsettingtable">' +
                                '<thead>' +
                                    '<tr>' +
                                    '<th>First Name</th>' +
                                    '<th>Last Name</th>' +
                                    '<th>Role</th>'+
                                    '<th>Email</th>' +
                                    '<th>School</th>'+
                                    '</tr>' +
                                '</thead>' +
                                '<tbody class="team_settings_row">';

                            var row = '';
                            var firstName = '';
                            var lastName = '';
                            var object = parseQueryList[i].get("organizer");    
                            var objectTwo = parseQueryList[i].get("coach");
                            var objectThree = parseQueryList[i].get("student");
                            var coachObjects = [];
                            var studentObjects = [];
                            var role ='';
                            var outerNumber;
                            var school = '';
                            var email = '';

                            for(outerNumber = 0; outerNumber < 3; ++outerNumber)
                            {
                                role ='';
                                // ORGANIZERS
                                if(outerNumber == 0)
                                {
                                    role = 'Organizer';                             
                                }
                                // coaches
                                else if(outerNumber == 1)
                                {
                                    role = 'Coach';
                                    object =  [];
                                    object = objectTwo;
                                }
                                // students
                                else{
                                    role = 'Student';
                                    object =  [];
                                    object = objectThree;
                                }

                                var q;
                                for (q = 0; q < object.length; ++q) 
                                {                               
                                    var t;  
                                    for(t = 0; t < userQueryList.length; ++t)
                                    {
                                        if(userQueryList[t].id == object[q])
                                        {
                                            firstName = userQueryList[t].get('firstName');
                                            lastName = userQueryList[t].get('lastName');
                                            school = userQueryList[t].get('school');
                                            email = userQueryList[t].get('email');
                                            row = row + 
                                            '<tr>' +
                                                '<td>'+ firstName +'</td>' +
                                                '<td>'+ lastName +'</td>' +
                                                '<td>'+ role +'</td>' +
                                                '<td>'+ '<a href="mailto:'+ email +'?Subject=Ethics Bowl:&body=body" target="_top">'+ email +'</a>' + '</td>'+
                                                '<td>'+ school + '</td>' +
                                            '</tr>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }                               

                            var ending = '</tbody>' +
                            '</table>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>';

            $('#dashboard_nav_team_settings_content').append(team_settings_content + row + ending);         

            //</TEAM SETTINGS PAGE>
        }
    }); 


    // declare simple log out
    $("#dashboard_log_out").click(function(event) 
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        Parse.User.logOut();
    });


    currentUser = Parse.User.current();
    if (currentUser) 
    {
        // user is logged in
    } 
    else 
    {
        // show the signup or login page
    }
});

function setUp()
{

    // perform a query as the page loads to figure out all the events
    currentUser = Parse.User.current();
    $("#dashboard_home_title_link").text("Ethics Bowls: " + currentUser.get("firstName"));
    var parseID = currentUser.id
    var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("ethicBowls");
    var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
    query.equalTo("userId", parseID);
    query.find({
        success: function(results) 
        {
            // save it for later
            parseQueryList = results;

            // more code down here meant for other things
        },
        error: function(error) 
        {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });

    var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("_User");
    var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
    query.equalTo("school", currentUser.get('school')); // get all users within the same school as current user
    query.find({
        success: function(users) {
            for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) 
            { 
                var object = users[i];
                userQueryList = users;
            }
        },
        error: function(error) 
        {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
}
```

Tried to be thorough but if I am missing some information, I'm happy to help. Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: `$(".bowlsettingtable tbody").on( "click", "tr", function(e) {
  alert('1');
 });` I tried this based on what Rory McCrossan said in his duplicate marking. It doesn't work either. I'm really stumped here

Comment: @humble.rumble I just tried that as well.It didn't fire the onclick listener either. I'm so confused right now why its not doing anything. `$(".bowlsettingtable").on('click', 'tr', function(){ alert (this.rowIndex); });` Thank you for trying though

Comment: Used both the exact code and the one I posted in the previous comment. Neither work. I'm wondering if there is conflict somewhere in my code which is preventing this onclick listener from firing.*slowly sobs as he returns to work*